# Poem in org-mode #+VERSE environment mangled by LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm using `org-mode` to create a handout for a poetry class in which I want to include John Hollander's "Swan and Shadow." It looks great in emacs, but when it's exported to PDF through LaTeX, it no longer looks like a swan and a shadow. In emacs:

[image]

Here it is with whitespace-mode active, to show that it's all spaces and not TABs:

[image]

And here it is in LaTeX-processed PDF:

[image]

What should I do to better preserve the appearance of this poem?

Comment: I'm curious how do you generate this verse ascii art in Org-mode #+BEGIN_VERSE block.

Comment: Well, I didn't really "generate" it by any means---I typed it in and lined everything up manually in the buffer. Then, as noted in my comment to the answer below, I ended up using a `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE` block instead of `VERSE` for monospaced output to PDF. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's just wrapping. Use a smaller font? A larger page?

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: aha, I figured it out. Your comment made me notice that the "water line" at the middle of the poem didn't need to wrap. In other words, it's the spaces that were a problem---they were too long in the font I'd chosen. I exchanged the `verse` block for an `example` block, in monospace, and now the poem looks correct.

Comment: Ah, indeed. The bill is also out of alignment for the same reason; the clues were right in front of our eyes.